# Rails view text_field existing value vs defaults

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking for a more elegant way to accomplish this.

```
  <div class="control-group">
<%= f.label :shoot_date, class: "control-label" %>
<div class="controls">
  <% if @shoot.new_record? %>
    <%= f.text_field :shoot_date, :class => 'datepicker', :value => Date.today.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), 'data-behavior' => 'datepicker', :readonly => true %>
  <% else %>
    <%= f.text_field :shoot_date, :class => 'datepicker', :value => @shoot.shoot_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'), 'data-behavior' => 'datepicker', :readonly => true %>      
  <% end %>
  <span class="help-block">Sitting date of this shoot.
</div>
```

Comment: It just occurred to me that I can set a default value in the controller for shoot.shoot_date = Date.today. Is this the best method?

Comment: That's exactly what you should do.

Comment: emm you should answer the question so I can give some points away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, just throw it in the controller:

```
def new
  shoot.shoot_date = Date.today
end
```

You shouldn't have to put it in the `edit` method or anything; that should happen automatically. You could even put it in the model if you like, but the controller works well.